# how to select from table untill the total is a specific number?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like this:

```
"ID"   "oamount"
'1'     '1500'
'2'     '2000'
'3'     '2000'
'4'     '1000'
```

and there is a buy order of 3000
so i need to select a query like this"

```
"ID"   "oamount"   "request"
'1'     '1500'       '1500'
'2'     '2000'       '1500'
```

and if the amount of the order is 4000 then

```
"ID"   "oamount"   "request"
'1'     '1500'       '1500'
'2'     '2000'       '2000'
'3'     '2000'       '500'
```

so i need to select all the rows until the amount is completed but the last row will represent the rest of the amount.

Comment: How can you tell that the amount is completed i.e how do you know that there isn't any remaining Id's with amount 500 or less so that mark  it as remaining???

Comment: where from `request` columns come??

Comment: request is the field i need to appear in the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it easier for yourself by adding an extra column, containing the sum of the amounts with a lower ID.

```
"ID" "oamount" "mamount"
'1'  '1500'    '0'
'2'  '2000'    '1500'
'3'  '2000'    '3500'
'4'  '1000'    '5500'
```

You can then select based on that new column:

```sql
SELECT `ID`,
    CASE WHEN `oamount` < @Amount - `mamount`
         THEN `oamount`
         ELSE @Amount - `mamount` END AS `amount`
FROM `yourtable`
WHERE `mamount` < @Amount
```

You *can* do it without adding this extra column, but you'll be making things unnecessarily hard.

Answer (score 3):

Try this query -

```
SET @req = 4000;
SET @sum = 0;
SELECT id, oamount, IF(s > @req, oamount - (s - @req), oamount) request FROM (
  SELECT id, oamount, @sum := @sum + oamount s FROM amounts ORDER BY id) t
WHERE s - oamount < @req;

+------+---------+---------+
| id   | oamount | request |
+------+---------+---------+
|    1 |    1500 |    1500 |
|    2 |    2000 |    2000 |
|    3 |    2000 |     500 |
+------+---------+---------+
```